# Drag and Drop content blocks on the page like web parts

Tags: jquery, asp.net, content-management-system, drag-and-drop, web-parts

I been testing Telerik Sitefinity CMS. I noticed drag and drop content blocks on the page like in the screen shot I am dragging and dropping content on the page and certain areas allow to drop those blocks with dashed lines.

Are there any tutorials or posts someone tried this and shared to achieve that kind of functionality?

Someone tell me is this webpart or jquery functionality?

anyone help me to the right direction please. just for learning purpose.

[image: Sitefinity CMS screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out `jQuery UI`. [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) & [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) in your case.